# Alternative SqlDependency for non-deterministic functions?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqldependency, non-deterministic

I need to use a `getdate()` function on SqlDependency but that is part of its [limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181122.aspx). (non-deterministic function)

What alternative do I have for it?

Comment: btw: Your link points to the german description...

Comment: Really? When opening up the link I see it in English.

Comment: Might be it gets translated... I'm living in a German speaking country and I'm pretty sure I See German 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function will be *deterministic*, if it returns the same value(s) always - as long as you call it with the same parameters against the same data. It is rather obvious, that functions like `GETDATE()` or `NEWID()` will not fullfill this requirement.

The only possibility I know about, is to pass in the non-deterministic value as a parameter. Check this out:

```
--This will return the current date, but is non-determinisitic
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TestFunc()
RETURNS DATETIME
WITH SCHEMABINDING
BEGIN
    RETURN GETDATE();
END
GO
--returns 0
SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[dbo].TestFunc'), 'IsDeterministic');
GO

--This is deterministic, as it returns nothing else, than the parameter
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TestFunc2(@CurrentDate DATETIME)
RETURNS DATETIME
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @CurrentDate;
END
GO
--returns 1
SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[dbo].TestFunc2'), 'IsDeterministic');
GO

--Both return the current date and time
SELECT dbo.TestFunc() AS NonDeterministic
      ,dbo.TestFunc2(GETDATE()) AS Deterministic; 
GO

--Cleaning
DROP FUNCTION dbo.TestFunc;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.TestFunc2;
```

Comment: Thank you! Although I realized the odd behavior of the SqlDependency (Query Notifications) does not allow monitor specific columns as I expected, this answer the question I asked!